# I have been offered another position within my company. My current manager is refusing to let me start until they have replaced me

Tags: notice-period, internal-transfer, replacement

There is nothing in my contract that covers internal transfers. If I had a new position externally I would have to give 30 days notice. My current manager is saying that they will not let me start my new position until she has filled my current roll. HR has said they will review it in a months time after the advert has gone live.... how long can they make me wait?

Comment: Sounds like a management issue to talk through, manager to manager (or to higher levels yet).

Comment: If there is nothing in your contract then it sounds like they can make you indefinitely. After all, you were apparently hired to do Job A and now you want to do Job B so it sounds like they have the ability to keep you at Job A until they successfully fill the position. That's the risk of being a contractor.

Comment: "My current manager is saying that they will not let me start my new position until she has filled my current roll"  Is this even her call to make?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere A difference without a distinction to my comment.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No, I think you're splitting hairs here. The posted mentioned having a contract and although they may not be a contractor, they are still bound by the contents of the contract so your initial comment was a difference without a distinction. Your second comment is simply pushing that same lack of distinction since all employer/employee relationships come with a degree of risk. The meat of my comment is what matters and holds true, not the minutia that you seem to want to argue.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is (essentially) "as long as it takes" - your notice period isn't relevant here since you aren't leaving the organisation.

Your manager isn't being especially unreasonable here - ideally you'd always have the option of having continuity like this. You can't enforce such a requirement when people are leaving the organisation altogether (and I'm sure we can all agree that *would* be unreasonable!) and notice periods are usually a way to mitigate that problem.

Practically speaking there's going to be a limit - the manager for your new role is going to want you to be starting at some point, and if your current manager isn't able to replace you quickly it's going to come down to a case of weighing the respective business needs of your new role versus keeping you in your old one.

There's probably not much you can, or *need* to do at this point - this is the sort of thing that the managers will have to sort out between them, with senior management stepping in if they can't.

In the meantime there's not much to do other than keep working, prepping for the knowledge transfer to whomever takes your old role and, if you have the bandwidth, start getting as much info as you can for the new one.

Comment: The caveat is that though your current manager wants to keep you, your **NEW** manager don't want to let that happen. From the business unit perspective, your salary is coming out of HIS budget, and you can bet your new manager isn't going to let the old manager have a free head count on his department's dime.